# String.contains() and stream.of.anymatch() returning false even when value is found

Tags: java

I have a string which is always different (variable), and i'm trying to check for certain characters in the string such as (, ), '.

but both string.contains and stream.of.anymatch() return false even when the characters are in the string.

it's in a for loop so I tried printing the string with the true or false statement everytime and this is what i get in the terminal.

```
//This is the print statement
 System.out.println(Stream.of("'", "(", ")").anyMatch(aLinesWords[0]::equalsIgnoreCase)+" => "+aLinesWords[0]);

//This is the terminal.
false => dsqd
false => 'ph'
false => 'sw'))
false =? dfaasf


//This is the if statement where I try checking for certain strings (which is not working)
if ( Stream.of("'", "(", ")").anyMatch(aLinesWords[0]::equalsIgnoreCase) ) {
     //Some irrelevant code.
    System.out.println("String found!");
}
```

Comment: You haven't used `String.contains()` anywhere, as your title would suggest.  `Stream.of().anyMatch()` will only tell you if there is an equivalent string in the stream.  Two strings are only equivalent if they are the same string of characters.  Two strings are not equivalent just because one contains the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contains` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase` because the character you are trying to match is not equal to the whole string; rather, the string contains the character.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "dsqd", "'ph'", "'sw'))", "dfaasf" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(Stream.of("'", "(", ")").anyMatch(s::contains) + " => " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false => dsqd
true => 'ph'
true => 'sw'))
false => dfaasf
```

Alternatively, you can do it using the java regex API. Use the regex, `['()]` which means `'` or `(` or `)`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] arr = { "dsqd", "'ph'", "'sw'))", "dfaasf" };
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("['()]");

        for (String s : arr) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            System.out.println(s + " => " + matcher.find());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
dsqd => false
'ph' => true
'sw')) => true
dfaasf => false
```